# Error 330 when Gzipping a response from nodejs server

Tags: node.js, gzip

I want to gzip a file hold it in memory and whenever a request comes from the client, i want to output the gzipped data. However I get a error 330 message on my browser (i am using the latest version of chrome)

The code below looks straight forward to me, is there something else I am missing?

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');
var zlib = require('zlib');
var gzippedData = '';

//read file into memory
fs.readFile('layout.html', function(err, data){
  if(err) throw err;
  zlib.gzip(data, function(err, buffer) {
    if (err) throw err;
    gzippedData = buffer.toString('binary');        
  });
});


var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
  var path = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
  switch (path){
    case '/': 
        res.writeHead(200, {'content-encoding': 'gzip'});
        res.write(gzippedData);
        res.end();
    break;
    default:  
      res.writeHead(404);
      res.write('404');
      res.end();
}});

server.listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
gzippedData = buffer.toString('binary');
```

to

```
gzippedData = buffer;
```

And you should be good to go!

**EDIT:** This is because `res.write` will encode the response as `utf8` by default. You could instead change that to `res.write(gzippedData, 'binary')`, but that's unnecessary. It's cheaper to just keep the reference to the buffer instead of allocating a js string and encoding that yet again.

Comment: It works!! cheers mate!

Is it really cheaper to hold a reference to the buffer, than holding the data in memory:
If you held a reference to the buffer wouldnt it mean all 1 million requests (for example) to the server, will have to pul the data out from the file

I thought it would be cheaper if the data is already held in memory, so that ll you are doing is flushing out...

Comment: Using the 1 milion request example again, If i held a reference to the buffer would that mean all 1 million requests would need to gzip a million times too? surely thats gotta be more expensive than, reading once, gzippping it and holding it in memory for all 1 million requests?.

Comment: I think you must misunderstand me. The file will be loaded once regardless. The only difference is that if you let `gzippedData = buffer`, you will just keep a single reference to that buffer. If you `gzippedData = buffer.toString('binary')`, you need to allocate that memory for a javascript string, and _then_ you need to encode that as `binary` on each request. I urge you to not take my word on this, but instead do a benchmark. You can log `process.memoryUsage()` between requests (or even in it's own request handler). Go `ab` on it!

Comment: Note that, since you want to `gzip` the file on startup, you could just keep it gzipped on disk and avoid having to do that in-process. Also, if my answer was to your satisfaction, please accept it by clicking the big check mark on the top left of my answer. That way you and I get karma, and other people can find the correct solution.

Comment: ...i didnt even know that was clickable :-/ (it wont let me vote though need 15 reps for that)

ah ok, i did misunderstand you, whilst trying to solve the problem i read alot of examples that suggested holding a reference to a stream using  fs.createReadStream and 'pipe' the output to a gzip object and pipe out to a writestream, seemed abit long-winded and thought you were referring to that, anyho thanks again :) 

yea thats a good idea, i'll gzip it on disk at the end after all changes